# CircleLayer Clusters not showing up in MapboxMap

Tags: android, mapbox-android

I'm trying to implement CircleLayer Clusters for MapboxMap with the help of this tutorial: https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/circle-layer-clustering/

In my app I receive 4 types of routes via API which i am already able to display in a source layer with their corresponding images. Now I want to add circle layer clustering for these 4 types of routes, but my circle layers aren't rendered on the map. Routes which are to far gone to get clustered are displayed as they should but none of my CircleLayers are showing up. That's the code i'm using to draw Route Markers and Clusters:

```
public void setRoutesToMap(FeatureCollection routesCollection) {
mapboxMap.getStyle(style -> {
    style.removeLayer(ROUTE_MARKER_LAYER);
    style.removeLayer(ROUTE_MARKER_CYCLING_CLUSTER_LAYER);
    style.removeLayer(ROUTE_MARKER_MTB_CLUSTER_LAYER);
    style.removeLayer(ROUTE_MARKER_SINGLETRAIL_CLUSTER_LAYER);
    style.removeLayer(ROUTE_MARKER_ROADBIKE_CLUSTER_LAYER);
    style.removeLayer(ROUTE_CLUSTER_COUNT_LAYER);
    style.removeSource(ROUTE_MARKER_SOURCE);
    // Disable any type of fading transition when icons collide on the map. This enhances the visual
    // look of the data clustering together and breaking apart.
    style.setTransition(new TransitionOptions(0, 0, false));
    //adding source (contains feature collection from which the markers get drawn)
    style.addSource(new GeoJsonSource(ROUTE_MARKER_SOURCE, routesCollection,
            new GeoJsonOptions().withCluster(true)
                    .withClusterMaxZoom(ROUTE_CLUSTER_MAX_ZOOM)
                    .withClusterRadius(ROUTE_CLUSTER_RADIUS)
                    //adding cluster property to distinguish types of clusters depending on the features route category
                    .withClusterProperty(MapboxHelper.ROUTE_PROPERTY_CATEGORY_CLUSTER, Expression.sum(Expression.accumulated(), Expression.get(MapboxHelper.ROUTE_PROPERTY_CATEGORY_CLUSTER)),
                            Expression.switchCase(
                                    //if route category equals BIKE_ROUTE, set cluster property to 1
                                    Expression.eq(Expression.get(MapboxHelper.ROUTE_PROPERTY_CATEGORY), RouteProperty.Category.BIKE_ROUTE), Expression.literal(1),
                                    //if route category equals MOUNTAINBIKE_ROUTE, set cluster property to 2
                                    Expression.eq(Expression.get(MapboxHelper.ROUTE_PROPERTY_CATEGORY), RouteProperty.Category.MOUNTAINBIKE_ROUTE), Expression.literal(2),
                                    //if route category equals SINGLETRAIL_ROUTE, set cluster property to 3
                                    Expression.eq(Expression.get(MapboxHelper.ROUTE_PROPERTY_CATEGORY), RouteProperty.Category.SINGLETRAIL_ROUTE), Expression.literal(3),
                                    //if route category equals ROADBIKE_ROUTE, set cluster property to 4
                                    Expression.eq(Expression.get(MapboxHelper.ROUTE_PROPERTY_CATEGORY), RouteProperty.Category.ROADBIKE_ROUTE), Expression.literal(4),
                                    //else set cluster property to 0
                                    Expression.literal(0)))
    ));
    //adding images with names of routes category so they get displayed with the correct category image
    style.addImage(RouteProperty.Category.BIKE_ROUTE, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.map_route_radwandern));
    style.addImage(RouteProperty.Category.MOUNTAINBIKE_ROUTE, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.map_route_mountainbike));
    style.addImage(RouteProperty.Category.SINGLETRAIL_ROUTE, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.map_route_singletrail));
    style.addImage(RouteProperty.Category.ROADBIKE_ROUTE, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.map_route_rennrad));
    //adding layer for unselected markers, images are used from category feature property
    style.addLayerBelow(new SymbolLayer(ROUTE_MARKER_LAYER, ROUTE_MARKER_SOURCE).withProperties(
            iconImage("{" + MapboxHelper.ROUTE_PROPERTY_CATEGORY + "}"),
            iconAllowOverlap(true)
    ), LOCATION_COMPONENT_BACKGROUND_LAYER);
    //Expression to filter whether we're displaying a cluster, since only clusters contain the property "point_count"
    Expression isCluster = Expression.has(MapboxHelper.PROPERTY_POINT_COUNT);
    //Expression to filter for clusters with cycling type
    Expression clusterCategoryCyclingFilter = Expression.eq(Expression.toNumber(Expression.get(MapboxHelper.ROUTE_PROPERTY_CATEGORY_CLUSTER)), Expression.literal(1));
    //Expression to filter for clusters with mountainbike type
    Expression clusterCategoryMountainbikeFilter = Expression.eq(Expression.toNumber(Expression.get(MapboxHelper.ROUTE_PROPERTY_CATEGORY_CLUSTER)), Expression.literal(2));
    //Expression to filter for clusters with singletrail type
    Expression clusterCategorySingletrailFilter = Expression.eq(Expression.toNumber(Expression.get(MapboxHelper.ROUTE_PROPERTY_CATEGORY_CLUSTER)), Expression.literal(3));
    //Expression to filter for clusters with roadbike type
    Expression clusterCategoryRoadbikeFilter = Expression.eq(Expression.toNumber(Expression.get(MapboxHelper.ROUTE_PROPERTY_CATEGORY_CLUSTER)), Expression.literal(4));
    //adding circle layer for cycling cluster with proper filter
    style.addLayer(new CircleLayer(ROUTE_MARKER_CYCLING_CLUSTER_LAYER, ROUTE_MARKER_SOURCE).withProperties(
            circleColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_cycling)),
            circleRadius(18f)
    ).withFilter(Expression.all(isCluster, clusterCategoryCyclingFilter)));
    //adding circle layer for mountainbike cluster with proper filter
    style.addLayer(new CircleLayer(ROUTE_MARKER_MTB_CLUSTER_LAYER, ROUTE_MARKER_SOURCE).withProperties(
            circleColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_mountainbike)),
            circleRadius(18f)
    ).withFilter(Expression.all(isCluster, clusterCategoryMountainbikeFilter)));
    //adding circle layer for singletrail cluster with proper filter
    style.addLayer(new CircleLayer(ROUTE_MARKER_SINGLETRAIL_CLUSTER_LAYER, ROUTE_MARKER_SOURCE).withProperties(
            circleColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_singletrail)),
            circleRadius(18f)
    ).withFilter(Expression.all(isCluster, clusterCategorySingletrailFilter)));
    //adding circle layer for roadbike cluster with proper filter
    style.addLayer(new CircleLayer(ROUTE_MARKER_ROADBIKE_CLUSTER_LAYER, ROUTE_MARKER_SOURCE).withProperties(
            circleColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_roadbike)),
            circleRadius(18f)
    ).withFilter(Expression.all(isCluster, clusterCategoryRoadbikeFilter)));
    //adding cluster count layer to display the amount of routes the cluster contains
    style.addLayer(new SymbolLayer(ROUTE_CLUSTER_COUNT_LAYER, ROUTE_MARKER_SOURCE).withProperties(
            textField(Expression.toString(Expression.get(MapboxHelper.PROPERTY_POINT_COUNT))),
            textSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_14)),
            textColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.applicationBackground)),
            textIgnorePlacement(true),
            textAllowOverlap(true)
    ));
});
if (getContext() == null) {
    return;
}
presenter.generateInfoWindows(getContext(), routesCollection);
}
```

I set the maxClusterZoom to 10 for testing purposes. When i zoom in to a zoom level greater than 10 my route markers show. When i zoom out again and they should get clustered, they are just gone since my ClusterLayer isn't showing up.
Any ideas on what i did wrong or what i am missing, that my CircleLayers aren't showing up?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was, that i'm using an offline-style.json file which hasn't declared a font by now. So i'm not able to display the numbers on my clusters for now until we declare a font in our offline-style.json. Just needed to comment out the Symbol layer which displays the number on the cluster until we declare a font in the style.json.